# Adding CITATION file to R package doesn't work

Tags: r, devtools

I'm writing an R package and have created a CITATION text document in my `inst` directory, currently containing the following text (which is unmodified from [Hadley Wickham's tutorial](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/inst.html)):

```
citHeader("To cite lubridate in publications use:")

citEntry(entry = "Article",
title        = "Dates and Times Made Easy with {lubridate}",
author       = personList(as.person("Garrett Grolemund"),
                 as.person("Hadley Wickham")),
journal      = "Journal of Statistical Software",
year         = "2011",
volume       = "40",
number       = "3",
pages        = "1--25",
url          = "http://www.jstatsoft.org/v40/i03/",

textVersion  =
paste("Garrett Grolemund, Hadley Wickham (2011).",
    "Dates and Times Made Easy with lubridate.",
    "Journal of Statistical Software, 40(3), 1-25.",
    "URL http://www.jstatsoft.org/v40/i03/.")
)
```

Then, I use the following calls to `devtools` to update the package documentation and load it locally:

```
library(devtools)
document()
build()
load_all()
```

But then, when I try `citation("MyNewPackage)`, I just get the default R citation. Nothing in the CITATION file appears.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: you need to install the package to make the citation available: after `library(devtools)`, run `install()`

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Did you reload your package with `library("MyNewPackage)` after installing it?

Comment: Yes, I did. No luck.